Start chrome without asking about being my default search engine?
Can I force Chrome to start without asking about being my default search engine?
I'am using nodriver and since its always a new profile, its always a problem. Didn't come before a few days, I don't know why now, but I struggle to handle with it.
Often he even use the "modal" for asking about the default search engine to start the website in it. Its really buggy then.

I dont want to use an existing profile.
I tried some browser_arghs, but they didnt help:
browser_args=[
    '--no-default-browser-check',
    '--no-first-run',
    '--disable-default-apps',
    '--disable-popup-blocking',
    '--disable-extensions',
]


You need to add disable-search-engine-choice-screen:

browser_args=[
    '--disable-search-engine-choice-screen',
    '--no-default-browser-check',
    '--no-first-run',
    '--disable-default-apps',
    '--disable-popup-blocking',
    '--disable-extensions',
]


Oh thanks! That works! I used Gemini Advanced and I did google and couldnt find it... ^^' And so simple, arghs...
Thanks a lot! :)
